# Lightroom: Changed default import location for a time period then reset it, those imports missing

Tags: lightroom, import

I am running Lightroom on a Surface Pro with limited SSD space so at one point I switched my default import location to an external MicroSD card.  My photo processing took a pretty serious performance hit using this as a location and after a number of months I tired of the performance issue and reverted to putting the imports back on the SSD.

At some point later I noticed that all the folders containing the imports from the MicroSD time period were missing.

Today I found the raws (on that MicroSD) and now I am wondering what would be the least problematic way of getting all these folders back into lightroom.
Would I lose any editing data if I (re)import them from the MicroSD?

I am using lightroom CC 2015.12, also I am not a big user of the Metadata if that comes into play.

Comment: I'll just say NEVER re-import or you loose changes. I did folder moves within the library.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to simply insert the MicroSD card, start Lightroom, then **in Lightroom**, drag and drop the folders that are on the SD Card to a folder that is on the SSD. Lightroom will probably prompt you to confirm the move. Lightroom will move the files from the SD card to the SSD.

Before doing this, you may wish to right click on the top-most SSD folder (in Lightroom) and choose "Show Parent Folder" so that you can drop them where you want.